# What is the proper way to translate strings from remote database on Android?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, google-translate, microsoft-translator

I have tried Google Translate and Microsoft Translator. Both give the error:

> [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : null
>     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I've set everything up according to references and tutorials. The only difference is that instead of calling Translate.execute() on click of a button, I'm trying to have it call as the JSON string data starts coming in.

Here's what I have:

**In My Data Model Class**

```
    public String getName() throws Exception {
        String trans = Translate.execute(prod_name, Language.ENGLISH, Language.fromString(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
        return trans;

    }
```

I've also tried this:

**In My Data Model Class**

```
    public String getName(){
        return prod_name;

    }
```

Along with this:

**Main Activity**

```
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(FEAT_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString()); try {
                            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                                String pid=response.getJSONObject(i).getString("pid");
                                String name=response.getJSONObject(i).getString("prod_name");
                                String img = response.getJSONObject(i).getString("prod_pic");

                                String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
                                Log.d("Response: ", name);
                                String trans = Translate.execute(name, Language.SPANISH, Language.fromString(lang));

                                fdata.add(new FeaturedModel(pid, trans, img));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } featAdapt=new FeaturedAdapter(MainActivity.this, fdata);
                        pageView.setAdapter(featAdapt);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        });

        VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, TAG);
```

I have seen other SO questions regarding Translate API's on Android but all of them referred to clicking a view to get the translation. I haven't found anything that gives an example of translating the JSON string response from a Volley request. Any ideas? What would be the proper way to do this without overloading the main thread?

**PER COMMENTS BELOW**
I've added this AsyncTask class to my MainActivity:

```
    class TranslateAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... inTxt) {
            try {
                String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
                translatedText = Translate.execute(inTxt, Language.fromString(lang));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Translate Error", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

And now getting an error that it can't resolve method setText(String[]) on this line in my adapter class:

> holder.ftitle.setText(feature.get(position).getName());

Looking at both the Google and Microsoft Translator API's, they require String[]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Volleys onResponse happens back on the main thread, so youd need to either switch to AsyncTask and implement your own callback routine or start a new background process for the translation in your response

Comment: @cricket_007 I've also tried performing the translation from within the adaptor after it receives the json response but still got the main thread exception. I can modify the translate class to be an async task class but could I still call that from within the Volley onResponse?

Comment: You can execute an AsyncTask anywhere, as far as I know, it's getting the onPostExecute data back to where you need it that's the tricky part

Comment: @cricket_007 I've added an asynctask class to my main activity but now my adapter says this line ` holder.ftitle.setText(feature.get(position).getName());` "Can't resolve method setText(String[])"

Comment: @rmtheis Thank you for that. Please read my above comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have, but setText doesn't take a string array

Comment: @cricket_007 I know but both Google and Microsoft Translate API's return string arrays for some reason.

Comment: I'm assuming it returns a list of possible translations, so you might be fine with the first element of the array